# PySpark - Unable to filter rows by another column's values

Tags: pyspark

I have been trying to get this simple code working, but without luck so far.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ('www.example.com/researc', 'Research Reports'),
    ('www.example.com/careers', 'Careers'),
    ('www.example.com/blogs', 'blogs'),
    ('www.example.com', None),
    ('www.example.com/navigation', None),
    ('www.example.com', 'main'),
    ('www.example.jp', None),
    ('', 'blogs')], ['A', 'B'])

display(df.toPandas())
df.printSchema()
print('Original DF')
display(df.toPandas())

filter_mask = df.where(df['B'].isNotNull())
print("\n\nFilter Mask")
display(filter_mask.toPandas())

print('\n\nfilter_mask[A]')
filter_mask.select('A').show()

# Why is "response" returning everything?!
response = df.filter(df['A'].isin(filter_mask['A']))
print("\n\nResulting DF")
display(response.toPandas())
```

I am trying to filter out all the null values from 'B', and then only keep the all the corresponding values in A; however my logic keeps on returning the entire dataframe.
Can somebody help me figure out why I'm not filtering the values correctly?

**Update**

So my desired output would be:

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|                   A|               B|
+--------------------+----------------+
|www.example.com/r...|Research Reports|
|www.example.com/c...|         Careers|
|www.example.com/b...|           blogs|
|     www.example.com|            null|
|     www.example.com|            main|
|                    |           blogs|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

^ Basically, I want to keep all URLs that are mapped to any non-null value in B. (So for "www.example.com", even though one of them maps to null, since another instance of it doesn't map to null; it is still returned in the final result.

Comment: can you provide desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.filter(df.B.isNotNull()).show()
```

Comment: add some explanation about your solution